# XHTML: banner (embedded divs)

Tags: html, xhtml, banner

I want to do the following:

```
------------------------------------------------
width: 100%;
height: 60px


                  image center


                               image bottom/right
-------------------------------------------------
```

I used to do it with table:

```
<table border="0">
<tr>
 <td width="25%"></td>
 <td width="50%"><center>image center</center></td>
 <td width="25%" valing bottom><div align="right">image bottom/right</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

but they say using tables for formatting is bad (Dunno why)
So is there any idea how to do the following banner? I heard there is `absolute` position, so mightbe the 2 images could be embedded to 2 divs

Answer (score 1):

First off before I do any explaining I think you could use some visuals of just how powerful CSS can be...

CSS Zen Garden shows how using a different CSS style sheet can completely change the entire way a site looks (use theme links on the right side)...

http://www.csszengarden.com/

My own site supports multiple themes which you can instantly change without even reloading the page...

http://www.jabcreations.com/blog/?prompt=themes-official

**1.)** Tables are intended for tabular data only, think the nutrition panels on food labels if you're not sure where to start. Tables are great for tabular data because it removes the formatting issues however you should never put non-tabular content in to tables as it disrupts the context of the content to search engines and you should instead use division elements instead since non-tabular data tends to do anything except for be presented in a tabular fashion.

**2.)** The context of using either CSS background-images or (X)HTML img (image) elements comes down to what you're trying to do.

**2.A.)** CSS3 allows the use of multiple background-images however browser support isn't yet universal when considering browser market shares...

http://www.caniuse.com/#search=css3%20multiple%20backgrounds

...as time passes however IE8 and other older browsers that do not support this modification to the CSS background-image property will slowly disappear so it will only become an increasingly viable option.

**2.B.)** You can combine an img element and a CSS background-image together to get two images to display inside of a single element.

**2.C.)** You can use two division elements with the same styling (or lack thereof) and then give them each a CSS background-image.

Here is the generally relevant CSS code...

```
background-image: url(kittens.png);

/* Choose one or the other below */
background-position: right bottom;
background-position: center center;
```

I'll reiterate that tables for on-tabular data is exceptionally bad for styling. Once you begin to grasp how CSS works (cascading means rules on lower lines override earlier lines, so the same rule on line 10 will override the same rule on line 9, if they are the same rule).

By using CSS you're going to have so much more power to quickly implement changes across your entire site and you'll be able to implement changes quicker and move on to more important things.